# how to handle click_action when app is in the foreground using firebase push notification in reactjs web app

Tags: reactjs, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to show push notification in the react web app. I am using the firebase push notification service for sending notifications. I know how to add click_action when the app is not in the foreground but I want to use click_action when the app is in the foreground but I don't know how to do this. I google it but no solution found for it.

I'm using the following code for the case when is in the background:

```
    self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    let url = 'my_url';
    event.notification.close();
    event.waitUntil(
        clients.matchAll({type: 'window'}).then( windowClients => {
            for (var i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
                var client = windowClients[i];
                if (client.url === url && 'focus' in client) {
                    return client.focus();
                }
            }
            if (clients.openWindow) {
                return clients.openWindow(url);
            }
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: If you want to handle the push message while in foreground, implement the `messaging.onMessage((payload) => {})` function in your service worker. [See here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive)

Comment: @AhmedM your solution is didn't work for me, it is giving me following error:-

code: "messaging/only-available-in-window"
message: "Messaging: This method is available in a Window context. (messaging/only-available-in-window)."

Comment: Sorry, you need to put it in your website's javascript not in the service worker. So that when a notification is received while user is browsing your website, this callback is executed.

Comment: @AhmedM I am repeating my question, I want that when the user is active on the website and when a push notification has arrived then the user is able to click on that notification. In my current flow push notification is showing to the user but when he clicks on the notification the click_action is not working. how can I do this? can you tell me?